# Keeping same gallery when calling fancybox with different classes

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I need to call fancybox in two different ways on a page--one with "`fitToView : false`" and one with "`fitToView : true`". I'd like to have these images in the same gallery, but since they're being called from two separate fancybox functions, it won't allow these to act as if they are in the same gallery. Is there a way to apply the "`fitToView : false`" dynamically or another solution that will help me achieve what I'm looking for?

Here are my two functions:

```
$('.fancybox')
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 5,
        fitToView : true,
        openEffect  : 'elastic'
    });
$('.fancyboxer')
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 5,
        fitToView : false,
        openEffect  : 'elastic'
    });
```

Comment: Try putting `AutoDimension: true`? instead of `fitToView`? this way you dont need to worry about the dimension of image

Comment: @KhawerZeshan : the option `autoDimensions` (not `AutoDimension`) is for fancybox v1.3.x and not compatible with v2.x and has nothing to do with fitting the image size in the view-port or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *[extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)* the fancybox API options for each element using the `afterLoad` callback.

But first, you would need a way to differentiate what elements will have `fitToView` set to `false` (default value is `true`)

You can achieve this by setting a special `class` in the anchor bound to fancybox (you will actually call fancybox with a **single** `class` for all elements) like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{target}">open image with fitToView : true (default)</a>
<a class="fancybox nofit" href="{target}">open image with fitToView : false</a>
```

**Notice** the second element has the class `nofit`; then within the `afterLoad` callback, evaluate if the current element has class `nofit` and *extend* the option `fitToView` set to `false` if so like :

```
$(function () {
    $(".fancybox")
    .attr("rel", "gallery")
    .fancybox({
        padding : 5,
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        afterLoad: function () {
            if ($(this.element).hasClass("nofit")) {
                $.extend(this, {
                    fitToView: false
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8UZYp/)**